# Session and remote IP address in grpc-go

Tags: grpc, grpc-go

In grpc-go, when implementing a service, the service interface defines methods contains only `Context` and `Request`. From the source of the `Context`, it is as simple as

```
type Context interface {
    Deadline() (deadline time.Time, ok bool)

    Done() <-chan struct{}

    Err() error

    Value(key interface{}) interface{}
}
```

So I wonder if it is possible to get some metadata (including remote IP address and other data) to maintain a session.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing that gRPC provides (in any language) that would be particularly robust as a session system across requests.

The streaming mechanism is great when you need to maintain context on a single server for clients: the stream callback's stack can point to whatever session information you need.

If you need state across separate RPC's (or across machines) you'll need to add your own session layer. You could do this by creating some unique id that you attach to (say) a 'my-session-id' metadata element when sending requests.

Comment: Isn't there already a unique ID associated with a channel, no? If I need to enforce my clients to attach a uid metadata when creating a channel, I will do it. But if grpc already has such a uid built-in, it would be preferable. thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to retrieve remote IP address through the use of [`stats.Handler`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/stats#Handler) (see especially this struct https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/v1.20.x/stats/stats.go#L89).

[`grpc.Metadata`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/Documentation/grpc-metadata.md) is commonly used to store arbitrary information about sessions.